# How do you create a thumbnail image out of a JPEG in Java?

Tags: java, image, jpeg

Can someone please help with some code for creating a thumbnail for a JPEG in Java.

I'm new at this, so a step by step explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java+thumbnail+jpg

Comment: Use a library like ImageMagick - lots of examples on the web

Comment: Oops, thanks for fixing my typos.  I prolly shouldn't introduce more typos after editing...

Answer (score 82):

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg")).getScaledInstance(100, 100, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

This will create a 100x100 pixels thumbnail as an Image object. If you want to write it back to disk simply convert the code to this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
img.createGraphics().drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg")).getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH),0,0,null);
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("test_thumb.jpg"));
```

Also if you are concerned about speed issues (the method described above is rather slow if you want to scale many images) use these methods and the following declaration :

```
private BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage source,double ratio) {
  int w = (int) (source.getWidth() * ratio);
  int h = (int) (source.getHeight() * ratio);
  BufferedImage bi = getCompatibleImage(w, h);
  Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
  double xScale = (double) w / source.getWidth();
  double yScale = (double) h / source.getHeight();
  AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(xScale,yScale);
  g2d.drawRenderedImage(source, at);
  g2d.dispose();
  return bi;
}

private BufferedImage getCompatibleImage(int w, int h) {
  GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
  GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
  BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h);
  return image;
}
```

And then call :

```
BufferedImage scaled = scale(img,0.5);
```

where 0.5 is the scale ratio and img is a BufferedImage containing the normal-sized image.

Comment: Would this code change with java.nio package? (writing back to disk)

Comment: @jacktrades no it wouldn't. You can use `ImageIO.write()` method to write it back to disk. I know, the comment is very old but for those whom are having the same question as jack.

Answer (score 36):

As you might have found out "easy" and "good looking result" are two very different things. I have encapsulated both of these requirements into a very simple [java image scaling library](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr) (Apache 2 license) that just does everything right for you.

Example code to create a thumbnail looks like this:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...); // load image
BufferedImage scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img, 150);
```

Your image proportions are honored, the library makes a best-guess at the method it should use based on the amount of change in the image due to scaling (FASTEST, BALANCED or QUALITY) and the best supported Java2D image types are always used to do the scaling to avoid the issue of "black" results or really terrible looking output (e.g. overly dithered GIF images).

Also, if you want to force it to output the best looking thumbnail possible in Java, the API call would look like this:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...); // load image
BufferedImage scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img, Method.QUALITY, 
                                       150, 100, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
```

Not only will the library use the Java2D recommended incremental scaling for you to give you the best looking result, it will also apply an optional antialiasing effect to the thumbnail (ConvolveOp with a very fine-tuned kernel) to every-so-slightly soften the transitions between pixel values so make the thumbnail look more uniform and not sharp or poppy as you might have seen when you go from very large images down to very small ones.

You can read through all the comments in the library (the code itself is doc'ed heavily) to see all the different JDK bugs that are worked around or optimizations that are made to improve the performance or memory usage. I spent a LOT of time tuning this implementation and have had a lot of good feedback from folks deploying it in web apps and other Java projects.

Comment: Thanks this lib is really awesome. None of the methods mentioned above worked on my test image, but your worked like a charm. I love the various resize options you've given.

Comment: @cracked_all thank you for the kind words; I am glad to hear it made your life easier!

Comment: This is a great library indeed. You should post it to Maven Central.

Comment: Hi Riyad, is your lib in maven central?

Answer (score 13):

This is simple way of creating a 100 X 100 thumbnail without any stretch or skew in image.

```
private  void saveScaledImage(String filePath,String outputFile){
    try {

        BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
        int width = sourceImage.getWidth();
        int height = sourceImage.getHeight();

        if(width>height){
            float extraSize=    height-100;
            float percentHight = (extraSize/height)*100;
            float percentWidth = width - ((width/100)*percentHight);
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)percentWidth, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Image scaledImage = sourceImage.getScaledInstance((int)percentWidth, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            img.createGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);
            BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(100, 100 ,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            img2 = img.getSubimage((int)((percentWidth-100)/2), 0, 100, 100);

            ImageIO.write(img2, "jpg", new File(outputFile));    
        }else{
            float extraSize=    width-100;
            float percentWidth = (extraSize/width)*100;
            float  percentHight = height - ((height/100)*percentWidth);
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, (int)percentHight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Image scaledImage = sourceImage.getScaledInstance(100,(int)percentHight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            img.createGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);
            BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(100, 100 ,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            img2 = img.getSubimage(0, (int)((percentHight-100)/2), 100, 100);

            ImageIO.write(img2, "jpg", new File(outputFile));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(100, 100 ,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

img2 = img.getSubimage((int)((percentWidth-100)/2), 0, 100, 100);

more correct is

BufferedImage img2 = img.getSubimage((int)((percentWidth-100)/2), 0, 100, 100);

Answer (score 4):

The [JMagick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick/) library (and implementation of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) in Java) will have what you need.

Comment: This just a native interface around ImageMagick. Problem 1.: external dependency Problem2.: calling native functions from Java. This makes JMagick suboptimal.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a pretty old post. I have been looking for a solution to generate the thumbnail so end up using this

```
Thumbnails.of(originalImage).scale(0.25).asBufferedImage();
```

if you are using for mobile would suggest to set the scale to 0.45

```
Thumbnails.of(originalImage).scale(0.45).asBufferedImage();
```

https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator

This is certainly much faster using the Graphics2D as have tested the both options.

Comment: thumbnailator can easily lead to [OutOfMemoryError](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/wiki/Changes#outofmemoryerror-workaround)

Comment: I've deployed this code on an AWS Lambda (Serverless). I haven't had this issue in 4 years.  This again depends on what's the use case.

Answer (score 3):

the Java code above (with the scale / getCompatibleImage methods) worked great for me, but when I deployed to a server, it stopped working, because the server had no display associated with it -- anyone else with this problem can fix it by using:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

instead of

```
BufferedImage bi = getCompatibleImage(w, h);
```

and deleting the `getCompatibleImage()` method

(later note -- it turns out this works great for most images, but I got a bunch from my companys marketing department that are 32 bit color depth jpeg images, and the library throws an unsupported image format exception for all of those :( -- imagemagick / jmagick are starting to look more appealing)

Answer (score 3):

I have writtena util class with static methods years ago using JAI. Java Advanced Imaging API is the most reliable API  in Java to deal with images. It's vector interpolation is closest thing to Photoshop in Java world. Here is one of them:

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream resize(InputStream inputStream , int IMG_WIDTH,
        int IMG_HEIGHT) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
    int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
            : originalImage.getType();
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,
            type);
    {
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "png", bos);
    return bos;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used Thumbnailator! It solved my problem with two lines of code.

https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to create a thumbnail without stretching or a library. Works with transparency in pngs, too.

```
public File createThumbnail(String imageUrl, String targetPath) {
    final int imageSize = 100;
    File thumbnail = new File(targetPath);

    try {
        thumbnail.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        thumbnail.createNewFile();
        BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imageUrl));
        float width = sourceImage.getWidth();
        float height = sourceImage.getHeight();

        BufferedImage img2;
        if (width > height) {
            float scaledWidth = (width / height) * (float) imageSize;
            float scaledHeight = imageSize;

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int) scaledWidth, (int) scaledHeight, sourceImage.getType());
            Image scaledImage = sourceImage.getScaledInstance((int) scaledWidth, (int) scaledHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            img.createGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);

            int offset = (int) ((scaledWidth - scaledHeight) / 2f);
            img2 = img.getSubimage(offset, 0, imageSize, imageSize);
        }
        else if (width < height) {
            float scaledWidth = imageSize;
            float scaledHeight = (height / width) * (float) imageSize;

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int) scaledWidth, (int) scaledHeight, sourceImage.getType());
            Image scaledImage = sourceImage.getScaledInstance((int) scaledWidth, (int) scaledHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            img.createGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);

            int offset = (int) ((scaledHeight - scaledWidth) / 2f);
            img2 = img.getSubimage(0, offset, imageSize, imageSize);
        }
        else {
            img2 = new BufferedImage(imageSize, imageSize, sourceImage.getType());
            Image scaledImage = sourceImage.getScaledInstance(imageSize, imageSize, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            img2.createGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
        ImageIO.write(img2, "png", thumbnail);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return thumbnail;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a application called fotovault (sourceforge.net) which can upload images and create thumbnails in java using imagej apis.

Please read my blog below

http://www.gingercart.com/Home/java-snippets/create-image-thumbnail-in-java-using-imagej-api

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through a blog according to which you have following options -

1. For simple RGB files use ImageScalr . ImageIO class is used for reading files and ImageScalr to create thumbnails
2. For supporting RGB + CYMK, use ImageIO and JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) API for reading files and ImageScalr to create thumbnail.
3. In case you don’t know what file formats, color mode you are going to deal with, safest option is to use ImageMagick.

Here is [**link**](http://paxcel.net/blog/java-thumbnail-generator-imagescalar-vs-imagemagic/) that gives a complete answer with code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

There are many image processing frameworks available that you can do this with just a few lines. The example below generates the thumbnails in different resolutions (given a width as reference) using [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/). The three thumbnails were generated in **92 ms**.

**input:**

[image]

**output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;

MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/input.jpg");
MarvinImage scaledImage = new MarvinImage(1,1);

scale(image, scaledImage, 250);
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(scaledImage, "./res/output_x250.jpg");

scale(image, scaledImage, 150);
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(scaledImage, "./res/output_x150.jpg");

scale(image, scaledImage, 50);
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(scaledImage, "./res/output_x50.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest approach would be:

```
static public BufferedImage scaleImage(BufferedImage image, int max_width, int max_height) {
    int img_width = image.getWidth();
    int img_height = image.getHeight();

    float horizontal_ratio = 1;
    float vertical_ratio    = 1;


    if(img_height > max_height) {
        vertical_ratio = (float)max_height / (float)img_height;
    }
    if(img_width > max_width) {
        horizontal_ratio = (float)max_width / (float)img_width;
    }

    float scale_ratio = 1;

    if (vertical_ratio < horizontal_ratio) {
        scale_ratio = vertical_ratio;
    }
    else if (horizontal_ratio < vertical_ratio) {
        scale_ratio = horizontal_ratio;
    }

    int dest_width  = (int) (img_width * scale_ratio);
    int dest_height = (int) (img_height * scale_ratio);

    BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(dest_width, dest_height, image.getType());
    Graphics graphics = scaled.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, dest_width, dest_height, null);
    graphics.dispose();

    return scaled;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the case when you want to create a quadrate `(75x75)` thumbnail from the non-quadrate source.

Code below first crop original image to quadrate using smaller size than resizes the quadrate image.

```
public static void generateThumbnailWithCrop(String imgPath, String thumbnailPath, int size) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));
    int width = sourceImage.getWidth();
    int height = sourceImage.getHeight();
    int smallerSize = width > height ? height : width;
    BufferedImage quadrateImage = cropToQuadrate(sourceImage, smallerSize);
    int type = quadrateImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : quadrateImage.getType();
    BufferedImage resizedImage = resizeImageWithHint(quadrateImage, type, size, size);
    File thumb = new File(thumbnailPath);
    thumb.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "jpg", thumb);
}

private static BufferedImage cropToQuadrate(BufferedImage sourceImage, int size) {
    BufferedImage img = sourceImage.getSubimage(0, 0, size, size);
    BufferedImage copyOfImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = copyOfImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    return copyOfImage;
}
private static BufferedImage resizeImageWithHint(BufferedImage originalImage, int type, int width, int height) {
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();

    return resizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Thumbnails4j](https://github.com/elastic/thumbnails4j) (I'm a maintainer, but it's owned by [Elastic](https://elastic.co)) is a java library that can be used to create thumbnails from image files, as well as from other file types.

```
File input = new File("/path/to/my_file.jpeg");
Thumbnailer thumbnailer = new ImageThumbnailer("png"); // or "jpg", whichever output format you want
List<Dimensions> outputDimensions = Collections.singletonList(new Dimensions(100, 100));
BufferedImage output = thumbnailer.getThumbnails(input, outputDimensions).get(0);
```

Comment: I couldn't use it in Kotlin application

Comment: Sorry to hear that @ShavkatTurakulov - what issues did you encounter? Please feel free to file a github issue. As it's a JVM project, it should work well with Kotlin, like any other Java library.