# Success stories of creating Thumbnail images on demand using java

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, jai

I have a bunch of images on a server. When client requests url for image, the client can specify to either receive the full image or get a thumbnail of the image. So, I'm looking to implement a servlet type solution that processes request, and generates thumbnail on demand if needed. It needs to support jpg, gif, tif, png.

It looks like using BufferedImage, JAI, and/or ImageMagick are the best options for java (from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069095/how-do-you-create-a-thumbnail-image-out-of-a-jpeg-in-java)). Any others I might have missed?

Also, has anyone implemented something similar in java? If so, any suggestions on a solution that gives (1) fairly descent quality thumbnails, (2) doesn't hog a huge amount of memory when it processes the images, (3) acceptable response time?

Comment: See: [*How to get a good quality thumbnail*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7742175/642706)

Answer (score 7):

[The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611)

Comment: This link is targeted to an invalid resource (the original site was closed).

Comment: @FelipeCaparelli, link has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

The core line of code for such a solution would be

```
img.getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

Where, if you don't like the quality, you can use `Image.SCALE_SMOOTH`.

I've been using this (surronded by some extras, like replacing a color with a pattern), on a not-so-active site (~300 users per day), but one which serves many images, and this hasn't caused any problems, so you can freely use it.

Use `ImageIO.write(image, formatName, response.getOutputStream())` for sending the image in the response.

Comment: ?? `ImageIO.write` takes a `RenderedImage` (such as `BufferedImage`) object in that first argument. But `java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance` returns a `java.awt.Image` object. A `java.awt.Image` is the superclass of `BufferedImage` but does *not* implement `RenderedImage`. So how are you passing the output of `img.getScaledInstance` to `ImageIO.write`? This is not possible in my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to do some systems call to a command line utility like non-java imagemagick and link output the generated file.

Comment: which is very developer-unfriendly

Answer (score 1):

See also [Loading large images as thumbnails without memory issues in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874593/909872) for a good answer about using javax.imagio.ImageReader to create thumbnails with minimal memory overhead.