# How to use Graphic2D drawstring and image with high quality using java?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Here is my code to generate QR code. I want to generate QR with string and image logo as below image. I have try to use rendering hint also but the result can not help on this.

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY)
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE)
```

```
def generateQrCodePNG(QRCodeModel qrCode) {
        int sizeW = 563
        int sizeH = 644
        try {
            BitMatrix byteMatrix = createBitMatrixPNG(qrCode.QRText, sizeW,sizeH)
            Integer CrunchifyWidth = byteMatrix.getWidth()
            Integer CrunchifyHeight = byteMatrix.getHeight()
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(CrunchifyWidth, CrunchifyHeight,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
            Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics()

            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE)
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, CrunchifyWidth, CrunchifyHeight)


            //clear font
            GraphicsEnvironment ge =
                    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()

            //Register Font
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("${servletContext.getRealPath("/")}/assets/fonts/KhmerOS_content.ttf")))
            graphics.setFont(new Font("Khmer OS Content", Font.PLAIN, 28))
            // add string title above qrCode
            drawString(graphics ,
                    graphics.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(qrCode.storeName) ,
                    450,CrunchifyWidth , CrunchifyHeight,qrCode.storeName ,
                    28,
                    "Khmer OS Content",
                    Color.BLACK
            )

            Integer h1 = sizeH
            Integer w1 = sizeW
            Integer x1 = (Integer) ((sizeW) / 2 - w1 / 2)
            Integer y1 = (Integer) ((sizeH) / 2 - h1 / 2)

            float dash1 = 10.0f
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK)
            BasicStroke dashed =
                    new BasicStroke(1.0f,
                            BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                            BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER,
                            10.0f, dash1 as float[], 0.0f)
            graphics.setStroke(dashed)
            graphics.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x1, y1,
                    CrunchifyWidth - 2 ,
                    CrunchifyHeight - 5 ,
                    1, 1))

            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK)
            for (int i = 0; i < CrunchifyWidth; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < CrunchifyHeight; j++) {
                    if (byteMatrix.get(i, j)) {
                        graphics.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1)
                    }
                }
            }
            if(qrCode.qr_type == Constant.QR_WITH_LOGO) {
                // set white background color
                graphics.setColor(Color.white)
                Integer h = 60
                Integer w = 60
                Integer x = (Integer) (CrunchifyWidth / 2 - w / 2)
                Integer y = (Integer) (CrunchifyHeight / 2 - h / 2)
                graphics.fillRoundRect(x,y,w,h, 10, 10)


                String logo = "${servletContext.getRealPath("/")}/assets/logo/AMK Mobile-Logo-high 1.png"

                //add  image into qrCode
                File fileLogo = new File(logo)
                Image logoImage1 = ImageIO.read(fileLogo)
                graphics.setColor(Color.white)
                Integer imgH = 55
                Integer imgW = 55
                Integer imgX = (Integer) (CrunchifyWidth / 2 - imgW / 2)
                Integer imgY = (Integer) (CrunchifyHeight / 2 - imgH / 2)
                graphics.drawImage(logoImage1, imgX, imgY, imgW, imgH, null)
            }

            //Register Font
            graphics.setFont(new Font("Khmer OS Content", Font.PLAIN, 24))
            // add string title above qrCode
            drawString(graphics ,
                    graphics.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(qrCode.cashier) ,
                    -450,CrunchifyWidth , CrunchifyHeight,qrCode.cashier ,
                    24,
                    "Khmer OS Content"
            )

            //Register Font
            graphics.setFont(new Font("Archive Regular", Font.PLAIN, 24))
            // add string title above qrCode
            drawString(graphics ,
                    graphics.getFontMetrics().stringWidth("${qrCode.account_id} | ${qrCode.currency}") ,
                    -550,CrunchifyWidth , CrunchifyHeight,"${qrCode.account_id} | ${qrCode.currency}" ,
                    24,
                    "Archive Regular"
            )

            graphics.dispose()
            File myFile = new File(qrCode.file_path + qrCode.file_name)
            ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", myFile)

        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nYou have successfully created QR Code.")
    }
```

Here is the result after generated, I got image png with bad quality text and logo when zoom the image:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266703/4910279

Comment: Ok thank you, Let me try

Comment: Your recommend code, The logo is look better but It's still blur when zoom the image.

Comment: Could you help me please?