# Android How to use Scalr 4.2 or 'java-image-scaling' for HQ thumbnails

Tags: android, android-layout, image-processing, scalr, imgscalr

I'm trying to create high quality thumbnails, have tried most-if-not-all methods with Android and not yet satisfied.

Here is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742175/how-to-get-a-good-quality-thumbnail) I found, in which I would like to try using Scalr or 'java-image-scaling' library for Android.

Here are [Scalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) and '[java-image-scaling](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/issues/list)'

**Question**: Can I use them in Android dev and How? (since I didn't see it mentions anywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to use `Scalr` with android because it uses `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, which isn't part of the Android SDK (neither is the rest of `java.awt`).

Android uses `android.graphics.Bitmap`, not BufferedImage.  I've yet to find as good of a library for Android as Scalr, but the Bitmap class support scaling, rotations and other transformations pretty well, look at [createBitmamp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) with the matrix parameter.

For example, the following code flips a bitmap, then saves it in another bitmap

```
Matrix mirrorMatrix = new Matrix();
mirrorMatrix.preScale(-.5f, .5f);
// Create a flipped sprite using the transform matrix and the original sprite
flippedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(orgBitmap, 0, 0, orgBitmap.getWidth(), orgBitmap.getHeight(),mirrorMatrix, true);
```