# How do you create a thumbnail for TIFF file in Java?

Tags: java

Can someone please help with some code for creating a thumbnail for a TIFF in Java.

Using this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069095/how-do-you-create-a-thumbnail-image-out-of-a-jpeg-in-java) I have created thumbnail for JPEG and PNG.

Comment: What have you tried? Why/how doesn't the code in the question you linked work? Post some code.

Comment: JavaIO can read TIFF files too.  Just notice there can be several actual images in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(aFile);
    BufferedImage thumbnNailImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = thumbnNailImage.createGraphics();
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    double xScale = (double) width / image.getWidth();
    double yScale = (double) height / image.getHeight();
    double scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

    double x = (width - image.getWidth() * scale) / 2;
    double y = (height - image.getHeight() * scale) / 2;
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(x, y);
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);
    g2.dispose();
    return thumbnNailImage;
```

When reading ImageIO.read(aFile); always returns null.

Comment: Just ignore the answer tag. I just want to reply

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11503648/edit) to add clarifications/code instead of posting an "answer".