# Creating Thumbnail for TIFF image in JAVA

Tags: java, tiff, jai, javax.imageio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't read and write a TIFF image file using Java ImageIO standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library)

Can someone please help with some code for creating a thumbnail for a TIFF in Java.
Using this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069095/how-do-you-create-a-thumbnail-image-out-of-a-jpeg-in-java) have created thumbnail for JPEG and PNG. I have used the below code to create thumbanail for PNG and JPEG

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(aFile);
    BufferedImage thumbnNailImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = thumbnNailImage.createGraphics();
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    double xScale = (double) width / image.getWidth();
    double yScale = (double) height / image.getHeight();
    double scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

    double x = (width - image.getWidth() * scale) / 2;
    double y = (height - image.getHeight() * scale) / 2;
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(x, y);
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);
    g2.dispose();
    return thumbnNailImage;
```

Comment: I understand that JAI provides an SPI for TIFF.

Comment: Can you please give some sample code snippet to do that