# Problems resizing an image

Tags: java, image, image-resizing

I´m trying to resize an image in Java but I have the next problem:
[image]

This is the original image, but after the resizing code, the result it´s this:
[image]

The code that I use it´s the next:

```
public BufferedImage res20x20(BufferedImage image){

    int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : image.getType();
    BufferedImage resizedIm= new BufferedImage(20, 20, type);
    Graphics2D g= resizedIm.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 20, 20, null);
    g.dispose();
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    return resizedIm;
}
```

The entire code can  be found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/).
The result that I want it´s this:
[image]

Comment: A Graphics object cannot be used after it has been disposed.  Even if it could, you are setting rendering hints after calling drawImage, so they would have no effect.  Set your rendering hints before you call drawImage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069095/how-do-you-create-a-thumbnail-image-out-of-a-jpeg-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public BufferedImage res20x20(BufferedImage image){

    int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : image.getType();
    BufferedImage resizedIm= new BufferedImage(20, 20, type);
    Image scaledImage = inputImage.getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    resizedIm.getGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);
    return resizedIm;
}
```

`Image.SCALE_SMOOTH` is the type of algorithm use to scale the image, you can try different values to get the result that better work for your needs